# Cannot run imagenet download and preprocess script (suggestion in issue 202 did not work)

Tags: tensorflow, imagenet

I am following the instruction here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

After running `bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train --num_gpus=1 --batch_size=32 --train_dir=/tmp/imagenet_train --data_dir=/tmp/imagenet_data`

I get the following error:

> bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/inception/inception/data/download_imagenet.sh: line 105: bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/inception/inception/data/imagenet_lsvrc_2015_synsets.txt: No such file or directory"

I saw the post on this in 202 but the suggestion to "add main before /inception" in work_dir did not solve the problem. Below is the output of `ls -l -R bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/`:

```
bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 parsa parsa 4096 Jun 30 14:34 inception
-r-xr-xr-x 1 parsa parsa 1737 Jun 30 14:34 MANIFEST

bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/inception:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 parsa parsa 4096 Jun 30 14:34 inception

bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/inception/inception:
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 149 Jun 30 14:34 build_imagenet_data -> /home/parsa/.cache/bazel/_bazel_parsa/cf59658e104287859f50b192c32a27cc/execroot/inception/bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/inception/build_imagenet_data
drwxr-xr-x 2 parsa parsa 4096 Jun 30 14:34 data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 162 Jun 30 14:34 download_and_preprocess_imagenet -> /home/parsa/.cache/bazel/_bazel_parsa/cf59658e104287859f50b192c32a27cc/execroot/inception/bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet
-r-xr-xr-x 1 parsa parsa 0 Jun 30 14:34 init.py

bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles/inception/inception/data:
total 32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 94 Jun 30 14:34 build_imagenet_data.py -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 107 Jun 30 14:34 download_and_preprocess_imagenet.sh -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 92 Jun 30 14:34 download_imagenet.sh -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/download_imagenet.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 114 Jun 30 14:34 imagenet_2012_validation_synset_labels.txt -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/imagenet_2012_validation_synset_labels.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 103 Jun 30 14:34 imagenet_lsvrc_2015_synsets.txt -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/imagenet_lsvrc_2015_synsets.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 93 Jun 30 14:34 imagenet_metadata.txt -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/imagenet_metadata.txt
-r-xr-xr-x 1 parsa parsa 0 Jun 30 14:34 init.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 110 Jun 30 14:34 preprocess_imagenet_validation_data.py -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/preprocess_imagenet_validation_data.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parsa parsa 97 Jun 30 14:34 process_bounding_boxes.py -> /home/parsa/Documents/development/brain/models/inception/inception/data/process_bounding_boxes.py
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: It's a known bug, need be fixed.

Comment: I am also getting the same error with Tensorflow 1.3 python 2.7 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the LABELS_FILE with the actual full file path in download_and_preprocess_imagenet.sh